# Reduce load cell creep and drift programatically

Tags: load-cell, strain-gage

I am trying to build a weigh scale and have read through the parameters that affect its reading in the long run. My question is can we reduce the Creep and drift of the load cell by compensation programmatically?
If so..How can I achieve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using HX711? Any calibration standards?

Comment: If the cell cycles from loaded to unloaded then you can use a window, to compare if the cell is unloaded then you do tare.

Comment: @tifong01 Yes..No calibration standards though